# Constructing a tibble from another tibble (without for loops?)

Tags: r

[tibbles documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html)

I've got this doing what I want, but it's using a for loop and I've read many times to avoid for loops in R for efficiency and style. Well, it's not a computationally demanding task and I think it might be as clear as it could be in a for loop. In any case, it seems a bit tricky to process this functionally rather than iteratively.

I'm starting with one tibble: `source_tbl`.
I want to make another tibble: `constructed_tbl`.
Every column in `constructed_tbl` is a sum of a subset of columns in `source_tbl`.

The column mapping is stored in `col_conversion_tbl`.

```
>print(col_conversion_tbl)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
source_col       constructed_col
<chr>            <chr>
1 col1             A
2 col2             A
3 col3             A
4 col4             A
5 col5             B
6 col6             B
```

So,
`constructed_tbl[,'A']`

should be equal to ...

`rowSums(source_tbl[,c('col1','col2','col3','col4')])`

### The best way I've come up with

The best way I've come up with is to

- convert `col_conversion_tbl` to a list, `col_conversion_lst`, where each item is an array of `source_col`s and is named after a `constructed_col`.
- initialize an empty `constructed_tbl` tibble w/ appropriate nrows, ncols, and column names
- Loop through `names(col_conversion_lst)` replacing the empty column from `constructed_tbl` with the sum of the appropriate columns from `source_tbl`.

### Here's my code

```
library(tibble)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

source_tbl <- tibble(col1=c(1,1,1),col2=c(2,2,2),col3=c(3,3,3),col4=c(4,4,4),col5=c(5,5,5),col6=c(6,6,6))
col_conversion_tbl <- tibble(source_col = c('col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6'), constructed_col = c('A','A','A','A','B','B'))

col_conversion_lst <- col_conversion_tbl %>% 
    split(.$constructed_col) %>% 
    map(~.$source_col)

constructed_tbl <- as_tibble(matrix(nrow=nrow(source_tbl),ncol= length(col_conversion_lst) ))
colnames(constructed_tbl) <- names(col_conversion_lst)  

for (n in names(col_conversion_lst)){
    constructed_tbl[,n] <- rowSums(source_tbl[ ,col_conversion_lst[[n]]])
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. You might want to include a reference about what a `tibble` is.

Comment: Thank you. I added a link, but shouldn't I expect that anyone who could answer this question would already know what a `tibble` is?

Comment: Sure, but don't expect the *readers* of your question to know what a tibble is. The more readers can understand of your code the easier it is to post an answer. I'd recommend taking a look at [Simon's Guide to posting a good question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562). In particular, you could improve {todo}.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a matrix multiplication. It is both efficient and leads to much shorter code, as you can see:

```
constructed_tbl <- as.tibble(as.matrix(source_tbl) %*% table(col_conversion_tbl))
```

Comment: This is a great answer. In reality, my `source_tbl` contains many more columns than just those listed in the `col_conversion_tbl`.  So in order to use this method I just need to add a line that selects only those columns in `source_tbl` that are found in `source_col` from `col_conversion_tbl`:    

  
`source_tbl <- source_tbl %>% select(col_conversion_tbl$source_col)`